# Find $a,b$ at $f(x)=\frac{x^2+x-12}{x^2-ax+b}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

An High school question:

> Given :$$f(x)=\frac{x^2+x-12}{x^2-ax+b}$$ it's given that $x=3$ is a vertical asymptote find $a$ and $b$.

**I tried:**

Since  $x=3$ is a vertical asymptote then $3^2-3a+b=0$, but now what

Comment: There is not enough information to decide $a$ and $b$

Comment: Asymptote, not asymptotics.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that $x^2+x-12$ also has $3$ as a root, so for an asymptote to exist we require $3$ to be a repeated root. Hence $x^2-ax+b=(x-3)^2\implies a=6,\,b=9$.

Comment: @greedoid Yes, because there's no $x-1$ factor to cancel in the numerator. But in the OP's question, we can cancel one $x-3$ factor.

Comment: @greedoid If you simplify $\frac{x^2+x-12}{x^2-6x+9}$ to $\frac{x+4}{x-3}$, you absolutely do have an $x=3$ asymptote.

Answer (score 5):

You can try also like that: Since $b= 3a-9$ we have $$f(x) = {(x+4)(x-3)\over x^2-ax+3a-9}= {(x+4)(x-3)\over (x-3)(x+3-a)} ={x+4\over x+3-a}$$

so $3-a=-3\implies a = 6$ and $b= 9$.